# Does the browser displays the page before JS file downloaded/executed

Tags: javascript, html, browser, html-rendering

I am wondering about how the browser displays the entire UI. I only know how the browser parses the HTML.

My question is does the browser gets displayed after HTML parsing and downloading the CSS even though the javascript file is still downloaded or still not executed

Comment: Without parsing how the browser understands the code. The point is your styles and external style sheets are just a reference. Once browser knows the meaning of particular class or style, then it will reflect the same visual in the page. Until the browser knows the meaning, the references(class, style) are just a unknown fields.

Comment: @MohanrajPonnambalam You mean the browser displays the page even though the js file is still downloaded/executed. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

When a browser sends a request to a server to fetch an HTML document, the server returns an HTML page in binary stream format which is a text file with the response header `Content-Type` set to the value `text/html; charset=UTF-8.`

Here `text/html` is a MIME Type which tells the browser that it is an `HTML` document and `charset=UTF-8` tells the browser that it is encoded in `UTF-8`character encoding. Using this information, the browser can convert the binary format into a readable text file.

If this header is missing, the browser would not understand how to process the file and it will render in plain text format. But if everything is OK, after this conversion, the browser can start reading the `HTML` document.

When the browser reads HTML code, whenever it encounters an `HTML` element like `html, body, div, etc.`, it creates a `JavaScript` object called a `Node`. Eventually, all `HTML` elements will be converted to `JavaScript` objects.

Since every `HTML` element has different properties, the Node object will be created from different classes (constructor functions). For example, the Node object for the `div` element is created from `HTMLDivElement` which inherits the Node class.

The browser comes with built-in classes like `HTMLDivElement, HTMLScriptElement, Node` etc.

After the browser has created Nodes from the `HTML` document, it has to create a tree-like structure of these node objects. Since our `HTML` elements in the `HTML` file are nested inside each other, the browser needs to replicate that but using Node objects it has previously created. This will help the browser efficiently render and manage the webpage throughout its lifecycle.

[image]

A `DOM` tree for an HTML document looks like the above. A `DOM` tree starts from the topmost element which is the HTML element and branches out as per the occurrence and nesting of HTML elements in the document. Whenever an HTML element is found, it creates a DOM node (Node) object from its respective class (constructor function).

There are different methods of applying styles to `HTML` elements like using an external `CSS` file, with embedded `CSS` using the `<style>` tag, with an inline method using the style attribute on HTML elements, or using JavaScript. But in the end, the browser has to do the heavy lifting of applying CSS styles to the DOM elements.

After constructing the `DOM`, the browser reads `CSS` from all the sources `(external, embedded, inline, user-agent, etc.)` and constructs a `CSSOM`. `CSSOM` stands for CSS Object Model which is a Tree Like structure just like `DOM`.

Each node in this tree contains `CSS` style information that will be applied to the `DOM` elements that it target (specified by the selector). `CSSOM`, however, does not contain `DOM` elements which can’t be printed on the screen like `<meta>, <script>, <title>` etc.

As we know, most of the browser comes with a stylesheet which is called a `user agent stylesheet`, the browser first computes final `CSS` properties for the `DOM` element by overriding user agent styles with `CSS` provided by the developer properties (using specificity rules) and then construct a node.

Even if a `CSS` property (such as a display) for a particular `HTML` element isn’t defined by either the developer or the browser, its value is set to the default value of that property as specified by the `W3C CSS` standard. While selecting the default value of a `CSS` property, some rules of inheritance are used if a property qualifies for the inheritance as mentioned in the `W3C documentation`.

For example, `color` and `font-size` among others inherit the value of the parent if these properties are missing for an `HTML` element. So you can imagine having these properties on an `HTML` element and all its children inheriting it. This is the very reason why the browser constructs a `CSSOM`, a `tree-like structure` to compute styles based on `CSS cascading rules`.